# Scanner not reading text from file

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am having an issue where I am trying to use Scanner to add elements to an arraylist from a text file. I have looked over my code what feels like a thousand times and I can't seem to find the issue.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fileNameSub)); //scanner object that locates the file
    scan.useDelimiter("\\n"); //delimiter for scanner

        ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>(); //create arraylist to hold txt file contents                

        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
            fileList.add(scan.nextLine());
        } // while loop that adds the contents so the arraylist
```

Please let me know if you see any errors that could be causing the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why use `scan.useDelimiter("\\n")`  also better to use a FileReader class

Answer (score 0):

Remove `scan.useDelimiter("\\n"`); and try again, or better use NIO2

```
List<String>lines = Files.readLines(Paths.get(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: I tried that and I am still not adding anything to the arraylist